# Looping through forms and submitting with AJAX with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a series of forms in a table on a page that I want to be able to submit with a single button that sits outside any of the forms.

So my HTML looks like this:

```
<button id="save_all">Save all</button>

<form class="form">… <button>Save</button></form>
<form class="form">… <button>Save</button></form>
<form class="form">… <button>Save</button></form>
```

At the moment, I have this, which is working for submitting individual forms:

```
function submitForms(form) {
    form.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let form = $(this),
            url = form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {}
        });
    });
}

$('.form button').click(function(){
    submitForms($(this).parents('form'));
});
```

But this doesn't work:

```
$('#save_all').click(function(){
    $('.form').each(function(){
        submitForms($(this));
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `submitForms` function does not submit the forms. It only adds a *submit* event listener. The only reason your forms submit is because you're clicking on the submit buttons.

Try something like this

```js
// This is your AJAX submitter, it returns a deferred object
const ajaxSubmit = (form) => $.ajax({
  url: form.action,
  method: form.method,
  data: $(form).serialize()
})

// Add individual submit handlers
const forms = $(".form").on("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  ajaxSubmit(e.target).done(data => {
    // handle response data here if you want
  })
})

// Submit all forms on click
$("#save_all").on("click", () => {
  forms.each((_, form) => {
    ajaxSubmit(form)
  })
})
```

---

And here's the obligatory [*You might not need jQuery*](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) version...

```js
const ajaxSubmit = form => {
  const data = new FormData(form)

  const init = {
    method: form.method
  }
  
  let url = form.action
  if (form.method.toUpperCase() === "POST") {
    init.body = form.enctype === "multipart/form-data" ? data
      : new URLSearchParams(data)
  } else {
    url = url.replace(/\?.+$/, '') + `?${new URLSearchParams(data)}`
  }

  return fetch(url, init)
}

const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form.form")
forms.forEach(form => {
  form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    ajaxSubmit(e.target)
  })
})

document.querySelector("#save_all").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  await Promise.all(Array.from(forms, ajaxSubmit))
})
```